# Sequential file display "System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+SelectedObjectCollection" when trying to add selected listbox items

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a program where user has to select items from the listbox(lstCommercial) and save to access file, problem is that only the last selected items shows in access file, here's my code

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim outfile As IO.StreamWriter
    Dim infile As IO.StreamReader

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lstCommercial.Items.Add("Cheerios")
        lstCommercial.Items.Add("Doritos")
        lstCommercial.Items.Add("T-mobile")
        lstCommercial.Items.Add("Radioshack")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

        ' open the file to create
        outfile = IO.File.CreateText("commercial.txt")

        ' write the name on a separate line in the file
        outfile.WriteLine(lstCommercial.SelectedItems)

        ' close the file
        lstCommercial.Focus()
        outfile.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

    End Sub
    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
' write the name on a separate line in the file
outfile.WriteLine(lstCommercial.SelectedItems)
```

...try this:

```
' write the name on a separate line in the file
For Each item In lstCommercial.SelectedItems
    outfile.WriteLine(item)
Next
```

The problem is that you're not iterating over all of the elements in the SelectedItems collection. Also, make sure you have the [SelectionMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectionmode(v=vs.110).aspx) property for your `lstCommercial` ListBox set to either MultiSimple or MultiExtended, and that you actually have multiple items selected when you click `btnSave`.

Comment: Its not showing error message anymore, but the file is only displaying the last selected item

Comment: @adalid_03 I fixed a minor syntax error in my code (`Next` instead of `End For`), and tested this successfully on my own machine. Please double-check the code you have, and in particular check what you have set for your ListBox control's SelectionMode property.

Comment: Yea I added the "Next" and selected MultiExtended because multiSimple will not allow me to save an item more then one. It's still only saving last selected item (

Comment: @adalid_03 Are you sure you have multiple items selected in your ListBox (such as by Shift+clicking them)? Because I can confirm that this code works on my machine, so you must be doing _something_ different. Otherwise, if you're trying to save _all_ of the items in the ListBox regardless of selection status, then you should be just iterating over the `Items` collection property instead. If you still can't get it to work, then I don't know what else to tell you.